# Unable to find type [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile]

Tags: .net, powershell, microsoft.build

I've suddenly got a problem with a script that has been running without problems previously

```
$sln = 'D:\[...]\[...].sln'
Add-Type -Path (${env:ProgramFiles(x86)} + '\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.2\Microsoft.Build.dll')
$slnFile = [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile]::Parse($sln)
```

The `Add-Type` seems to work without an error, but the next line keeps throwing an error

```
Unable to find type [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile].
At D:\[...]\[scriptname].ps1:7 char:13
+     $slnFile = [Microsoft.Build.Construction.SolutionFile]::Parse($sl ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Build...on.SolutionFile:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

The script was based on several examples

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49600306
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41753608
- [Where solution build order is saved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46345658)

And it worked in the past. I'm still pointing to the same old Microsoft.Build.dll assembly. Can anybody explain to me what's changed?

Comment: Perhaps you can find out more if you do ``try{ Add-Type -Path "<pathToDll>"} catch [System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException] {
"Message: $($_.Exception.Message)`r`nStackTrace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)`r`nLoaderExceptions: $($_.Exception.LoaderExceptions)"}``

Comment: @Theo that gives no result. The Add-Type seems to work. I also see the assembly in the list when I run `[System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`.